1980-1990s thriller mystery movie with a female detective
Probably this is going to be really vague, but i cant remember anything apart from these scenes.
The movie is probably from 1980s or mostly from 1990s. English, saw it on HBO/Star Movies almost 10 - 13 years back. I cant recall the actress but i this she may be famous.
The movie has a scene in a bathroom (public bathroom) where a murder might have taken place and the heroine is out to investigate the bathroom. and i think she is attacked in the bathroom / or maybe threatned.
She also investigates an old building where she finds a hole in the wall and there is so much once you go into the hole (looks like a whole different place where the murderer stayed)
I remember the movie being in yellow tones. I will hopefully try to add any more details I can remember. These scenes have been running in my head for weeks and its kind of a creepy feeling.

Not V. I. Warshawski?

I cant gather from the description, but ill watch(skim) through it once to confirm..
